# FInd element by ID then get content in XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
  <string id="test-text">Some sample text from XML</string>
  <string id="test-text2">Some more sample text</string>
</data>
```

Which I have loaded into a XmlDocument object, and I'm trying to get the text using the id. I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but this is how I'm currently trying to do it.

```
    XmlElement elem = doc.GetElementById("test-text");
    return elem.Value;
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

[GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only work with ID attributes defined via DTD (unlikely scenario, definitely not in case of your sample):

> ... this version of the product only supports those defined in DTDs. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD. Implementations where it is unknown whether the attributes are of type ID are expected to return null.

You want basic XPath with attribute check:

```
var d = new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml(@"<data>
  <string id='test-text'>Some sample text from XML</string>
  <string id='test-text2'>Some more sample text</string>
</data>");
var elem = d.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='test-text']");
Console.WriteLine(elem.InnerText);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/UkM6UZ)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `elem.InnerText` rather than `elem.Value.`

From the class documentation, `InnerText` [Gets or sets the concatenated values of the node and all its children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), while `Value` is a property inherited from `XmlNode` that is useful for attribute nodes, text nodes, etc. but doesn't really apply to nodes like `XmlElement`.  In a DOM tree built from your document, the XmlElement you're finding would contain a `Text` node whose `Value` is the string you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately my XmlElement elem isn't set to a value, so that won't work either until thats fixed

Comment: @WilliamDunne, Okay, so what's the value of the `key` variable?

Comment: it is currently "test-text"

Comment: @WilliamDunne, Hm, seems like that should work.  How is `doc` being created?  What is `doc.InnerXml`?

Comment: This is what I pulled from the debugger:

"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><data><string id=\"test-text\">Some sample text from XML</string><string id=\"test-text2\">Some more sample text</string></data>"